# Recover data from a diskpart > clean command

Tags: windows, data-recovery

I managed to clean my 2TB backup external hard drive, while attempting to clean a USB-stick for making a bootable Windows 8 installation.

Now the help file for the diskpart > clean command says `only the MBR partitioning information and hidden sector information are overwritten`.
I realized what I did exactly after executing the command:

```
 On master boot record (MBR) disks, only the MBR partitioning information
 and hidden sector information are overwritten. On GUID partition table
 (GPT) disks, the GPT partitioning information, including the Protective
 MBR, is overwritten. If the ALL parameter is not used, the first 1MB
 and the last 1MB of the disk are zeroed. This erases any disk formatting
 that had been previously applied to the disk. The disk's state after
 cleaning the disk is 'UNINITIALIZED'.
```

I am aware of the fact that most recovery programs don't succeed 100%, but I am still looking for a sure-shot way to recover the data, as I don't have another backup.
In other words, I want a program that recovers as much data as possible.

Some notes on the current state of the HDD

- I stopped exactly after hitting the clean command and no operation has been performed on the HDD since.
- The HDD had **no partitions** on it, it was a single 2TB partition
- I am running Windows 8.1 Pro

Is there a program that can recover my data?

**Update**
>

> I did exactly as suggested in this answer, but that unfortunately didn't work for me.
>   https://superuser.com/q/472838/85063

Comment: I edited the question to specify that it has to be a program, so it stays on-topic. Hope you don't mind